# Unable to set the weight of buttons inside scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I am trying to set the set of buttons inside the ScrollView to equal weight. I tried using the following code but it does not work. Anyone has any idea how to set the buttons to equal weight?

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/b1" android:text="@string/s1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b2" android:text="@string/s2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:fillViewport="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/bShortcut1" android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/bShortcut2" android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/bShortcut3" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bShortcut31" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/bShortcut4" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/bShortcut5" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/bShortcut6" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am not clear on the exact behavior of ScrollViews, but it is my assumption that they are unbound, so that if you want the weight attribute to work properly, you should set a hardcoded limit in dp to your enclosing LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

It will not wot work for sure.

- Actually what you did, is you assigned weight of 1 to each button. Now this means that the actual width of parent, i.e. linear layout in your case, will be distributed equally among all the buttons.
- And you have also set the attribute `android:layout_width="wrap_content`"  for linear Layout. this means its width will be actuaaly the sum of widths of all the buttons.

it means both of your layouts are **interdependent** on each other.

Comment: I have tried setting the layout_width for Linear layout to "fill_parent" but that doesn't help either. Those button inside the scrollview is still having unequal width.

Comment: just remove the weight attribute. either hardcode the width of the buttons or set it to wrap-content.

Comment: Look like there is no choice but to hardcoded the width then. Thanks, it work after i hardcoded it and remove the weight attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual problem you are facing? Are you seeing the buttons at all?

I would say replace android:layout_width="0dp" to wrap_content and try again.

Comment: the problem is all the button inside the scroll view has different width. I have tried replacing their layout_width=0dp but that doesn't help

Comment: Can you try setting LinearLayout width as fill_parent